# Is $x^2$ uniformly continuous on $\Bbb{R^+}?$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, uniform-continuity

I want to know if $x^2$ is uniformly continuous on $\Bbb{R^+}$. This kind of question [Prove that $f(x)=x^2$ is uniformly continuous on any bounded interval.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260254/prove-that-fx-x2-is-uniformly-continuous-on-any-bounded-interval) has been asked before but not on $\Bbb{R^+}$.

I know of a Theorem that states that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,\infty)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ exists then $f$ is uniformly continuous. Can anyone help me show if $x^2$ is uniformly continuous on $\Bbb{R^+}$ based on this Theorem?

Comment: So what is $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x^2$?  You seem to say that this limit exists...

Comment: @Eric Towers: Oh! Sorry for the typo.

Comment: "uniformly continuous" is sort-of-equivalent to "having bounded derivative".

Comment: @ Alex Vong: $\sup\limits_{x\in (0,\infty)}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}x^2=+\infty$ right?

Comment: @Mike I was wrong.

Comment: @ Alex Vong: No problems about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For uniform continuity, you need to show that given $\def\e{\varepsilon}\e>0$, that there exists a $\delta>0$ so $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $$|x^2-y^2|=|x-y|\cdot|x+y|=\delta|x+y|<\e.$$ But the quantity $|x+y|$ is unbounded, even when you assume $|x-y|<\delta$. Just take $y=x+\delta/2$ to see that $\delta|x+y|$ can get arbitrarily large. In particular, you cannot choose $\delta$ so the above holds for all $x,y$ which are with $\delta$ of each other.